# Cannot understand how FragmentPagerAdapter works under activity destruction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm testing my app with 'destroy all activities as soon as user leaves it' to simulate the OS killing my app.

In my main activity, in onCreate, I instantiate all the fragments, add them to a list and then:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Here is the adapter code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return getString(R.string.section_one);
            case 1: return getString(R.string.section_two);
            case 2: return getString(R.string.section_three);
            case 3: return getString(R.string.section_four);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem (crash) lies here, in an action bar item:

```
 case R.id.action_refresh: 
    PostsFragment fragment = (PostsFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    fragment.reloadDataFromServer();
```

Say the activity was opened, then destroyed on the back button. When I return to this activity and press the refresh action item, the app crashes. Why? When the activity is created again, it creates a new pager adapter, with all new 4 fragments. But onCreate of these fragments is never called, none of the members are initialized, so the reloadDataFromServer fails loading into a listview that hasn't been initialized yet.

HOWEVER, the onCreate of the previous referenced fragments IS called, but we no longer have a reference to them because we recreated the FragmentPagerAdapter with new fragments. This is driving me INSANE! Why is onCreate not called for the new fragments?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has problems with this, I'll explain my solution. Basically what happens is fragments that were created before are restored on recreation of the activity after a destruction. This may be a *duh* moment for some of you.

My problem is essentially having incorrect references to fragments.

First, I changed the setOffscreenPageLimit to the full (#tabs - 1). This means all fragments are created at the start and held in memory. I'll explain why this helps later.

This means in onSaveInstanceState, we can use putFragment on all 4 fragments with the outState Bundle.

In create, if savedInstanceState is null, we can create all 4 fragments from scratch. Otherwise, you can use getFragment on all 4 fragments and place them into the new pager adapter to hold as reference.

You may ask why I set setOffscreenPageLimit to max. I had problems with figuring out which fragments to save with putFragment. isAdded() did not seem to always work properly, neither did isResumed(), so it was easier to just save all of them because we know all 4 were created and were in the fragment manager at all times.